# Swift - tableview contentsize doesnt match content?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

Ok Ive been struggling with this for a while now - basically I have a tableview set up via storyboard that I now need to modify its content size via code.

Basically the issue is I have these tableview cells, and I overlap a view (same height as 1 cell for both overlap views) on the top and bottom of this tableview. This works fine as Ive shifted down the tableview in position.y like this:

[image]

However I have the problem when I scroll to the bottom - I cant fully see the last 2 cells. Other than add 2 dummy cells all the time (because I am constantly reloading my tableview data/number of cells) which seems wrong, I cant fix this.

What I have tried is EVERY time I reload I do:

```
  func fixTableHeight()
    {

        //just make bigger
        self.myTableView.contentSize.height *= 1.1

          self.myTableView.contentSize.height = rssListToLoad + (height of 1) //TEMP

        //print("HI: ",self.myTableView.contentSize.height)

    }

 self.myTableView.reloadData()
    self.fixTableHeight() //**MUST BE AFTER RELOAD DATA!!
```

But this then results in some infinite loop of extending the table height. Other methods have flat out not worked.

What can I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` so treat them the same with respect to content size. You need to stretch the content view at the bottom, not arbitrarily increase its size, so just add a table footer:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 100))
```

If you need to include safe areas, add the footer in a lifecycle method like `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and add the inset values there.

Answer (score -1):

minimize the height of tableview via storyboard.@skyguy